# git track branch with different name

Tags: git, git-branch

I have a repo which tracks non-default branches. So, there is a local branch named "master" which should track "origin/master-13.07". I've done "push -u", and I believe it should be enough, the branch is tracked. Output of the `git branch -vv`:

```
C:\work\repo>git branch -vv
  stuff     68792df [origin/stuff-13.07] Small bugfix
* master 68792df [origin/master-13.07: ahead 1] Small bugfix
```

Output of the `git status`

```
C:\work\repo>git status
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master-13.07' by 1 commit.
#   (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
#
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

All seems all right, but when I just use "git push" (as git recommends me above), it fails:

```
C:\work\repo>git push
fatal: The upstream branch of your current branch does not match
the name of your current branch.  To push to the upstream branch
on the remote, use

    git push origin HEAD:master-13.07

To push to the branch of the same name on the remote, use

    git push origin master
```

Yes, I know that the name doesn't match, this is exactly what I want and I told so to git by "push -u". Why I cannot just use "push"?

```
C:\work\repo>git --version
git version 1.8.3.msysgit.0

C:\work\repo>git config push.default
simple
```

Comment: Which Git version do you use ? Did you set `push.default` option ?

Comment: @GuillaumeDarmont I've added info to the question

Comment: @GuillaumeDarmont Seems solution is to change the `push.default` to `upstream`. Thanks.

Comment: Cool. Added a cleaner answer for other users.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Ok. With the informations you added, I think you simply have to change `push.default` to value `upstream`.

You probably configured the actual value after upgrading Git and seeing this message :

```
warning: push.default is unset; its implicit value is changing in 
Git 2.0 from 'matching' to 'simple'. To squelch this message 
and maintain the current behavior after the default changes, use: 

  git config --global push.default matching

To squelch this message and adopt the new behavior now, use: 

  git config --global push.default simple
```

According to the documentation, value `simple` must reject a push when branch names are different. See [Git Config](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config.html) (search for `push.default`).

Answer (score 0):

With Git 2.20 (Q4 2018), the advice will slightly change.

See [commit 8247166](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8247166717fc5a3f26e4db1067891da12644808b) (13 Nov 2018) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 2c23f0b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2c23f0b67e5ef908ee9ead3154199d4ad5f8b577), 01 Dec 2018)</sup>

> ### `push`: change needlessly ambiguous example in error
>
> Change an example push added in [b55e677](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b55e67752242b449a4577c05341fd6b2fea4d310) ("push: introduce new `push.default` mode "`simple`"", 2012-04-24, v1.7.11-rc0) to always mean the same thing whether the current setting happens to be "`simple`" or not.
>
> This error is only emitted under "`simple`", but message is explaining to the user that they can get two sorts of different behaviors by these two invocations.
>
> Let's use:
>
> - "**`git push <remote> HEAD`**" which always means push the current branch name to that remote,
> - instead of "`git push <remote> <current-branch-name>`" which will do that under "`simple`", but is not guaranteed to do under "`upstream`".