# Make current branch 'leo' push to the remote branch 'origin/leonardo_da_vinci'

Tags: git, branch, git-push

Situation:

- Remote repository has branch `leonardo_da_vinci`
- Your local repository has branch `leo`

In the local repository, I want to push `leo <-> leonardo_da_vinci`
with the command `git push origin`
(no following `leo:...` because I forget this).
**How?**

You can easily do it with `git push origin leo:leonardo_da_vinci`,
but how to config git to use `git push`?

I tried using `--set-upstream-to`, `--track`, 
and adding to `.git/config` the line `push = refs/head/leo:leonardo_da_vinci` into branch `leo` section.
No luck.

Here is `.git/config`:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = /some_url/
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[branch "leo"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/leonardo_da_vinci
[branch "origin/leonardo_da_vinci"]
    remote = .
    merge = refs/heads/leo
```

My git config has `push.default` set to `simple`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the branch `leo` is the one checked out, a simple `git push` will be enough, because the upstream branch `leonardo_da_vinci` has been set ([with `git branch -u`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4879224/6309), or [after the first `git push -u origin leonardo_da_vinci`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6232535/6309))

If you would need at least `git push origin leo`.

But not `git push leo`, as the first parameter of `git push` is the remote, not the branch.

Make sure that `git config push.default` is set to **`upstream`**.
See "[git - push current vs. push upstream (tracking)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13751847/6309)".

Comment: hm, i will try using `git branch -u` again, somehow this didn't work before -- command `git push origin` resulted in pushing _new_ branch `leo` into remote repo, instead of pushing changes into `leonardo_da_vinci`. (yes, even after the first `push` was with `u` option.

Comment: @Ayrat Then try `git checkout leo; git push -u origin leo leonardo_da_vinci`; then future `git push` will work.

Comment: No, it does not work. Git says: `fatal: The upstream branch of your current branch does not match the name of your current branch...`, and suggests using `git push origin leo:leonardo_da_vinci` syntax. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24865780/801203) is suggested to rename the local branch. May be the only solution.

Comment: @Ayrat that because of the push.default policy. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/17045911/6309 and set it to 'upstream".